# Are there regional foods in Westeros?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

With the regions, Kingdoms and countries of GRRM's world influence by Britain and Europe are the any regional foods similar to the area in question or just regional foods in general?

e.g. Haggis north of the wall

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are some, not so many. While of course given the cultural and ethnic diversity along with relative isolation of the people one would expect full fledge cuisines for every Kingdom but that is not really the point of the story so GRRM doesn't dwell on all that too much. To cite a few food items that are explicitly tied with one region:

#### Food

- [Bowl o' Brown](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Bowl_of_brown), a delicacy from King's Landing. You do not want to know what goes in it.
- [Sister's Stew](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sister%27s_stew) - A dish from the three Sister, very imaginatively named.
- [Dornish Cuisine](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dornishmen#Culinary_arts) - Individual dishes are not known but Dornish cuisine is said to be very different from other Westerosi foods. Dornish prefer their food hot and flavoured with strange spices (even snake's venom).

#### Drinks

1. North is famous for her fine beer and mead.
2. Arbor is famous for her red and gold wine.
3. Dorne is famous for her Red wine.
4. Reach in general famous for sweet red wines.
5. Wolf's Den's beer is famous in both Essos and Westeros.
6. Highgarden is known for its Hippocras.
7. Lannisport is known for its spiced Honey wine.
8. The monks at Quiet Isle are famed for their cider and mead.

Comment: The Maester's not for punning!

Comment: So no appearance on Maesterchef then?

Comment: I would not call the bowls of brown a delicacy...

Comment: Let's not forget the folk north of the Wall. I think the Thenns have some good ethnic cuisine.

Comment: Don't forget the Dornish lemons...

Comment: Is lamprey pie specific to any one region?

Comment: @Brad I believe we have seen people from multiple kingdoms enjoying those I'm afraid no. Could be that it began somewhere and then spread everywhere but if that's the case, we do not know

Answer (score 18):

Actually the books go in some detail describing food and dishes. At the [Inn at the CrossRoads](http://www.innatthecrossroads.com/home/game-thrones-recipes/got-landing-page/) blog you can find the list of food referenced in each region and the attempt to recreate the recipes. Assumption goes what is referenced in the text tends to be typical of the location.

Bonus track, there is a kind of official recipes book for Westeros endorsed by GRRM (up to you to decide if it makes it canon or a smart marketing stunt): [A Feast of Ice and Fire](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345534492).

Comment: AFOIAF is in my Amazon basket, we'll see how it goes...